# I run through this issue while building apk file

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-operator

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cached_video_player:verifyReleaseResources'.        
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\Mazen\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e1db1d7e58d402c8040729c1f98d1141\transformed\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           28.4s        
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I don't run through this while building app through emulator just while building apk and I tried mostly everything not working

Comment: Could you try running your command in verbose mode. Eg: `flutter build apk --verbose`. And attach the logs here.

Comment: check minSdk and compileSdk versions in build.grade